# Revising SQL query to return user's own posts?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Currently, the query works fine and does as its supposed to do. However, I'd like to change the query so it retrieves the user's own posts in addition to the other posts. How can I do this? I've tried things like `OR P.author = $_SESSION['username']` but it seems this results in each of the user's own posts being echoed multiple times.

```
$gtPsts = "SELECT P.id, P.subid, P.author, P.post, P.access, P.date, F.friends, F.following, F.f1, F.f2, F.status 
    FROM posts AS P, friends AS F 
    WHERE (F.f1 = '$_SESSION[username]' AND F.f2 = P.author AND F.status = 1 AND P.access = 'Public' OR P.access = 'Friends') 
    OR (F.f2 = '$_SESSION[username]' AND F.f1 = P.author AND F.status = 1 AND P.access = 'Public' OR P.access = 'Friends') 
    OR (F.f1 = '$_SESSION[username]' AND F.f2 = P.author AND F.following = True AND P.access = 'Public' OR P.access = 'Following') 
    ORDER BY P.date DESC LIMIT 20";
```

Structure of table is as follows: `id (int)`, `subid (int)`, `author (varchar)`, `post (longtext)`, `access (varchar)`, `date (datetime)`.

Comment: Could you post the structure of your table?

Comment: `I've tried things like OR P.author = $_SESSION['username']` Where exactly did you try adding this in the query?

Comment: What is the aim of `OR 'Friends'` clause ? It always evaluates to `false`. Either this clause can be removed or it's a sign of some logic error.

Comment: @kordirko I'm guessing the intention of that was really `AND P.access IN ( 'Public', 'Friends')`

Comment: @kordirko Actually I have no idea why that's there. This is inside of a PHP class file I don't access often. I was probably trying to get this query to find the user's own posts some months ago, and forgot to remove that line when I stopped. Mikey Dinescu I've tried adding it to the beginning of the query and to the end, but as I've said, to no avail.

Comment: Updated OP. Just realized what I was trying to accomplish with the `OR 'Friends'` line.

Comment: @Elitis I said that in my comment above, but wrote it in a more compact fashion for you :p take a look.

Comment: Also the change you just made is not what you think it is. be careful when using "or"... usually needs parentheses.

Comment: @Mikey So is there something significant about the placement of that line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the users' own posts multiple times because the query joins your two tables `posts` and `friends`. So if you filter for `(P.author = $_SESSION['username'])`, you get one of his `posts` together with each item in the `friends` table.

You could use a workaround. If your `friends` table has a primary/unique key, let's say `id`, you could use `OR (P.author = '$_SESSION[username]' AND F.id = (SELECT id FROM friends LIMIT 1))`. There must be a more performant way, but this should already help.